# How to Retrieve a Zip Folder from FTP in Python

Tags: python, ftp, zip

I'm trying to retrieve a zip folder(s) from an ftp site and save them to my local machine, using python (ideally I'd like to specify where they are saved on my C:).

The code below connects to the FTP site and then *something happens in the PyScripter window that looks like random characters for about 1000 lines... but nothing actually gets downloaded to my hard drive.

Any tips?

```
import ftplib
import sys

def gettext(ftp, filename, outfile=None):
    # fetch a text file
    if outfile is None:
        outfile = sys.stdout
    # use a lambda to add newlines to the lines read from the server
    ftp.retrlines("RETR " + filename, lambda s, w=outfile.write: w(s+"\n"))

def getbinary(ftp, filename, outfile=None):
    # fetch a binary file
    if outfile is None:
        outfile = sys.stdout
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + filename, outfile.write)

ftp = ftplib.FTP("FTP IP Address")
ftp.login("username", "password")
ftp.cwd("/MCPA")

#gettext(ftp, "subbdy.zip")
getbinary(ftp, "subbdy.zip")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems that you simply forgot to open the file you want to write into.

Something like:

```
getbinary(ftp, "subbdy.zip", open(r'C:\Path\to\subbdy.zip', 'wb'))
```